# SQL in Access - Use LIKE to find a value from a column in another column

Tags: sql, ms-access

I used access, i have two columns in T1  :

| col1 | col2 | col3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| AA | AA-rtz | 1234 |
| AB | AA-rtz | 1239 |

I want to get with sql access all registers in T1 where col1 is a string from col2, also :

| col1 | col2 | col3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| AA | AA-rtz | 1234 |
|  | AA-rtz | 1239 |

I use :

```
Select * from T1 where col1 like col2 + '*'
```

Whats wrong?

Thank you very much

Comment: the answer works if your data is exactly as shown, but if you are failing because the string parsing functions can't parse your data properly then you need to use regular expressions.  Like most modern languages Access-VBA has regular expressions.  For example, http://www.icodeguru.com/database/access.hacks/0596009240/accesshks-chp-5-sect-16.html

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
 Select * from T1 where LEFT(col2,2) = col1
```

This assumes your data is as shown above. You can modify the LEFT function's second argument to suit your situation otherwise - (At the moment it looks at the first 2 characters from the left).

Comment: Thank you @Nick  it works but it gib just one result, not two. Like mazoula says, to parse one string from col1 into col2 i need to use regular expressions.  But Thank you very much all